# Como simplificar las convoluciones

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

```
def Convolucion(ImpulsoL, ImpulsoR, Canal1, Canal2, Canal3, Canal4):
      ConvLW = signal.fftconvolve(Canal1,ImpulsoL,mode='full')
      ConvRW = signal.fftconvolve(Canal1,ImpulsoR,mode='full')
      ConvLX = signal.fftconvolve(Canal2,ImpulsoL,mode='full')
      ConvRX = signal.fftconvolve(Canal2,ImpulsoR,mode='full')
      ConvLY = signal.fftconvolve(Canal3,ImpulsoL,mode='full')
      ConvRY = signal.fftconvolve(Canal3,ImpulsoR,mode='full')
      ConvLZ = signal.fftconvolve(Canal4,ImpulsoL,mode='full')
      ConvRZ = signal.fftconvolve(Canal4,ImpulsoR,mode='full')
      return ConvLW, ConvRW, ConvLX, ConvRX, ConvLY, ConvRY, ConvLZ, ConvRZ

[ConvolucionL1_W, ConvolucionR1_W,ConvolucionL1_X,ConvolucionR1_X,ConvolucionL1_Y,ConvolucionR1_Y,ConvolucionL1_Z,ConvolucionR1_Z] = Convolucion(ImpulsoL_1,ImpulsoR_1,CanalW,CanalX,CanalY,CanalZ)
[ConvolucionL2_W, ConvolucionR2_W,ConvolucionL2_X,ConvolucionR2_X,ConvolucionL2_Y,ConvolucionR2_Y,ConvolucionL2_Z,ConvolucionR2_Z] = Convolucion(ImpulsoL_2,ImpulsoR_2,CanalW,CanalX,CanalY,CanalZ)
[ConvolucionL3_W, ConvolucionR3_W,ConvolucionL3_X,ConvolucionR3_X,ConvolucionL3_Y,ConvolucionR3_Y,ConvolucionL3_Z,ConvolucionR3_Z] = Convolucion(ImpulsoL_3,ImpulsoR_3,CanalW,CanalX,CanalY,CanalZ)
[ConvolucionL4_W, ConvolucionR4_W,ConvolucionL4_X,ConvolucionR4_X,ConvolucionL4_Y,ConvolucionR4_Y,ConvolucionL4_Z,ConvolucionR4_Z] = Convolucion(ImpulsoL_4,ImpulsoR_4,CanalW,CanalX,CanalY,CanalZ)
```

Estoy realizando un proceso de convolucion entre unas respuestas al impulso L y R,con los canales W, X, Y y Z. El problema es que este proceso se debe hacer 37 veces y al momento de correr el programa el computador se pone lento y nunca termina de ejecutar todo el código. Como podría hacer que no se demore la computadora y simplificar este proceso. Algún consejo.

Comment: Supongo que usas `scipy`. ¿De qué tamaño son las matrices?¿Has probado con `convolve` en vez de `fftconvolve`?

Comment: Si estoy utilizando scipy import signal, las matrices son alrededor de longitud 2690240. Estuve revisando la documentación de scipy signal y ahí mencionan que fftconvolve era mejor para matrices mayores a 500, por eso la utilice.

Comment: Posiblemente hayas llegado al límite de cómputo de tu computador. Puedes probar otras técnicas como usar GPU (revisa https://laurentperrinet.github.io/sciblog/posts/2017-09-20-the-fastest-2d-convolution-in-the-world.html), pero sólo vas a acelerar el proceso si reduces el tamaño de las matrices.